# inline function in relation to the stack

Tags: c++, memory

I want to know what will be going on the stack when using an inline function .
What will be the sequence of the pushed stuff in the stack if a simple inlined function is called from the main function.and how it is going to be in case of a normal function.

Another question how does inlining affect the attributed place for the compiled code in memory.

Comment: When a function is expanded inline, there may be no stack usage at all. If it's expanded inline, the code will normally be generated with the other code at the call site.

Answer (score 2):

You can reasonably model a "call" to an inlined function *similar to* a macro expansion, for example:

```
inline double f(double a, double b, double c) { return a * b + 2 / (c + b); }

// caller...
double x = 10;
double y = f(x, 2.3 * x, -9.0);
```

...is generally similar to...

```
double x = 10;
double _b = 2.3 * x;
double y = x * _b + 2 / (-9.0 + _b);
```

Except that "`_b`" is not a named variable that you can refer to later.  Note that I list `_b` explicitly to highlight that `2.3 * x` will be calculated once as it's prepared for the "`b`" parameter.  This is ***different to a macro expansion*** like the following where it's evaluated twice:

```
#define F(A, B, C) ((A) * (B) + 2 / (C + B))
// double y = F(x, 2.3 * x, -9.0);
double y = ((x) * (2.3 * x) + 2 / (-9.0 + (2.3 * x)));
```

The language grants the compiler freedom to use different code if there's no observable difference in the side effects on program state, I/O etc., so it could consider repeat the `2.3 * x` calculation as per the macro, but my intuition is that they're not functionally equivalent - I imagine there're small rounding differences, and probably different thresholds for overflow, but I haven't sweated over the details.

So, it's not a question of " the sequence of the pushed stuff in the stack" for an inlined call - you can basically discount the idea that it's any manner of "call" and just think about the code as if the steps were directly in the calling code.

> Another question how does inlining affect the attributed place for the compiled code in memory.

Again, the generated code is as if there had been no call, so the debugger is likely to report execution stepping through the "caller" without any mention of the inlined function.  Debuggers are free to do whatever they like though, so on some system a compiler *could* annotate the debug symbol data in some way that let the compiler make mention of the inlined function at moments it deemed appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the stack is very much dependent on the CPU you are compiling for. With an INTEL 32bit processor, you have *so few registers* that it very often has to put the variables on the stack. On a 64bit processor, they added 8 registers, making the usage of the stack less prominent. On a MIPS processor, you have 32 registers and most often can do everything with those registers without the need to rely on the stack. On a Cray system (with the old vectorized processors) you have 64 files of 64 registers, in case you needed to do some matrix calculations... on a GPU such as an NVidia you may have 16 registers x number of threads which could be 1,500 for example, so 24,000 registers.

So without knowing what architecture you are targeting, which compiler you are using, answering your question is not going to be an exact science. That being said...

`inline` may or may not have an impact on the stack depending on whether the compiler is happy with inlining your code or not and whether the function itself needs to use the stack for its computations.

Actually, in C++ you are likely to use the Standard C++ Libraries which are nearly all templates. This means, all of that code is inlined when used. So for example when you write code to retrieve the size of a vector:

```
my_vector.size();
```

It gets inlined. And in most cases this means, processor wise on an INTEL system, something like this (AT&T notation):

```
mov (%eax), %ebx
```

Now if you were to look at the vector implementation, your first reaction should be to get really scared. Yet, the compiler does a lot of magic and can completely optimize those (the main cost is the time and memory it takes to compile all of that... and in that regard, memory wise cl is limited, the Microsoft C++ compiler.)

Now, if you get the size of your vector to call another function which is not going to get inlined, something like this:

```
complicated_function(my_vector.size());
```

Then the result is something like this as the size needs to be sent to the function being called:

```
mov (%eax), %ebx
push %ebx                    ; end up stacking the size() from the inlined call
call complicated_function    ; this pushes the return PC on the stack
add $4, %esp
```

Note, again, that on some systems, they use registers in their calling convention so you may not use the stack for that. On a MIPS processor, for example, you have no need for the stack at all at the point:

```
ld $r3, ($r9)                ; get vector size (inlined)
jal complicated_function     ; call another sub-function
```

(not totally sure what the general convention is for MIPS registers, but the code would look very similar to what I show here.)

And in complicated_function() $al may not even need to be saved on the stack. (because the jal does not push the current $pc on the stack, it saves it in the $al register instead!)

For the last part of your question: were does the code go when inlining? Obviously it goes where you called the function replacing it with the instructions of the compiled inlined function, assuming it gets inlined, of course.

Another interesting behavior, if your functions returns a constant value (i.e. a value that is known at compile time) then the compiler is likely to optimize your code even more. Even if your function has a very complicated expression. You may be interested in looking at the `constexpr` keyword, which I think is better than the `inline` keyword when you can make use of it:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Finally, since you are asking about inline you may be interested by the always_inline attribute, that's specific to g++, but it can interest you:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about an inlined function and not simply one with inline linkage. By definition, if the compiler has inlined a function, there is no explicit function call at the calling site because the compiler has replaced the call with the body of the function. Thus, there will be no stack setup for the call. However, the local variables declared and used in the original body of this function remain local variables in the inlined code as well - they will be allocated on the stack like any other automatic duration variables.

About the second part of your question - "how does inlining affect the attributed place for the compiled code in memory" - if all the calls to this function are inlined, the linker needn't even include a definition for this function. However, if there are calls to it that are not inlineable, this function will have a definition like any other function.

Answer (score 0):

Inlining is not an obligation to the compiler but rather a request. Compiler can as well inline methods which are not qualified by "inline" keyword. It depends upon the compiler optimization  flag. If the Compiler ever decides to inline then all the inline calls are replaced by function-body but if the compiler decides not to inline, it would behave just like any other methods. Try debugging your program using disassembly symbols with optimization ON and OFF to see the difference yourself.